# Парсинг JSON в SQL и последующее обновление

Tags: php, sql, json

Всем добрый день. Есть сервис который работает с файлом в json формате. Это выгрузка, которая прилетает ко мне ежедневно. Хочу перевести это в sql формат средствами php, но не могу придумать механизм, который бы это дело перевёл в таблицу. Я так понимаю сначала его надо спарсить а потом что-то типа: $query = "insert into test values (NULL, '$text')"; А самое сложное, что вызывает вопрос, как обновлять значения уже имеющейся базы на основе json файла.

```
<!-- содежимое test.json -->
[
    {
        "ID": "000000001",
        "Obj": "Данные об объекте 1",
        "proc_gotov": "100",
        "vvod": "01.10.2017",
        "current": "В процессе"
    },
    {
        "ID": "000000001",
        "Obj": "Данные об объекте 1",
        "proc_gotov": "100",
        "vvod": "01.11.2017",
        "current": "В процессе"
    },
    {
        "ID": "000000001",
        "Obj": "Данные об объекте 1",
        "proc_gotov": "100",
        "vvod": "01.12.2017",
        "current": "В процессе"
    },
    {
        "ID": "000000002",
        "Obj": "Данные об объекте 2",
        "proc_gotov": "10",
        "vvod": "01.05.2018",
        "current": "В процессе"
    },
    {
        "ID": "000000002",
        "Obj": "Данные об объекте 2",
        "proc_gotov": "10",
        "vvod": "01.05.2018",
        "current": "В процессе"
    },
    {
        "ID": "000000003",
        "Obj": "Данные об объекте 3",
        "proc_gotov": "100",
        "vvod": "01.12.2016",
        "current": "Готов"
    },
    {
        "ID": "000000003",
        "Obj": "Данные об объекте 3",
        "proc_gotov": "100",
        "vvod": "01.12.2016",
        "current": "Готов"
    },
    {
        "ID": "000000003",
        "Obj": "Данные об объекте 3",
        "proc_gotov": "100",
        "vvod": "01.12.2016",
        "current": "Готов"
    }

]
```

Comment: структуру таблицы бы добавили

Comment: @rjhdby дак нет ее еще

Comment: вы таблицу то в базе аналогичной структуры создайте, и храните сами данные, а не json-файл в ней.

Comment: @teran я так и хочу, перенести данные из файла в таблицу, а потом обновлять её, на основе данных которые будет содержать ежедневно обновляющийся json файл.

Answer (score 1):

```
$db = new mysqli(...);
$data = json_decode($json);

$stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO table (id, obj, proc, vvod, current) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE SET proc_gotov=?");
$row = $data[0];
$stmt->bind_values("ssisss", $row['ID'], $row['Obj'], $row['proc_gotov'], $row['vvod'], $row['current'], $row['proc_gotov']);
foreach($data as $row){
    $stmt->execute();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Воспользуйтесь `SELECT * FROM OPENJSON(@json)`.

Вот здесь очень хорошо описано: https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sql/relational-databases/json/json-data-sql-server

Comment: первая ссылка из гугла что ли? вы где то видели что в вопросе была пометка про SQL Server да еще и последнего выпуска 2016 ?

Comment: Нужно именно средствами php, пример кода. Установка SQL Server не подходит для меня